# Multiproccesing зависает при большом колве процессов

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, python-2.7

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такой код:

```
def actions(host,i):
    while True:
           time.sleep(1)

def main():
    hosts = []
    with open('host.txt') as hosts_file:
        for line in hosts_file:
                    hosts.append(line.strip())


    for (i, host) in enumerate(hosts):
    thread = Process(target=actions, args=(host,i))        
            thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
            main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Код берет список хостов из файла hosts.txt и отправляет каждый хост из файла в свой процесс (аля многопоточность), в котором с каждым хостом бесконечно производятся некоторые действия с таймаутом. Проблема в том что даже если функция actions без основного кода (как в примере выше), спустя некоторое время со старта программа зависает как и вся ОС (Ubuntu 16.04), вроде как сжирается вся оперативная память, а ее 32GB. Подскажите пожалуйста как оптимизировать этот код.

Comment: ограничить количество одновременно обрабатываемых хостов, очевидно

Comment: В любом случае они должны все обрабатываться бесконечно!

Comment: да, но но если ты запустишь слишком много процессов на каждый хост, а у тебя их, наверное много (уточни), то ты зависнешь.

Comment: у меня 3000 хостов, на каждый хост нужен 1 беконечный процесс

Comment: значит тебе придется добавить гору памяти. либо обрабатывать их пачками поменьше. посмотри сколько памяти жрет один процесс питона и умножь на 3к, я уверен, что ты можешь переключаться между пачками хостов, а если тебе рил-тайм на 3к хостов нужен, то мультипроцессинговый питон тебе точно не подойдет

Comment: Хорошо допустим откажемся от бесконечных процессов и сделаем бесконечный цикл, я раньше работал в php, и не догоняю как сделать бесконечный цикл который будет с шагом в 100 хостов например на python.

Comment: какая разница, php или python?  в php тоже можно мультипроцессно работать, ты программист или кто, епрст. добавь счетчик в `for line in hosts_file:` , и там дальше смотри

Answer (score 2):

Оптимизация номер ноль - уточнить задачу, придумать другой подход к решению. Скорее всего можно обойтись и без 3000 параллельно обрабатывающихся задач.

Первая оптимизация - это перейти с процессов на потоки. Я так понял что задача нагружает I/O. Потоки в этом случае памяти будут тратить точно меньше чем процессы.

Вторая оптимизация - все таки 3000 потоков тоже не мало, и если памяти будет все равно не хватать, тогда можно попробовать сделать приложение асинхронным, посмотрите в сторону [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: Да, процессы и потоки, подкреплённые ОСью, здесь скорее всего тяжеловесны и не нужны. Можно gevent, twisted попробовать, чтобы одновременно действия над всеми узлами производить.